What would be effects if sun was smaller, but had same mass?
What would be the effects on Earth if the sun was half its current diameter, but retained the same mass?

at our suns end of life this exact thing will happen.

The power output of the sun is given by the Stefan-Boltzman equation:
$$P = \sigma T^4 A$$ where $\sigma$ is Stefan-Boltzman constant, T is the temperature, and A is the surface area. The surface area of the sun is $A = 4\pi R^2$ where R is the radius of the sun so
$$P = 4\pi\sigma T^4 R^2$$
If the Sun was half its diameter with the same mass and temperature, the power output would be reduced by a factor of 4. The earth would receive less energy/time and be considerably cooler.

If the sun's mass was compacted into half its current size, does this necessarily cause the temperature output to decrease? It would seem temperature would increase even though luminosity would decrease.
